# PHP - Accesses Uploaded file from from dir with temp URL

Tags: php

I'm creating a page where user can upload their files and view the file if they want but challenge it, i do not want to show exact file path where file exists in my project, looking for something where user can access file with temp folder location something look like below mention URL

**Original File Path**

```
/files/upload/documents/example.pdf
```

**URL for access original file**

```
www.example.com/files/upload/documents/example.pdf
```

**Temporary URL to access file**

```
www.example.com/temp/example.pdf
```

Looking for something, so user can access file with a temporary URL.

Answer (score 0):

If it's core PHP then You can use this code:

```
<?php
$path = explode("/",$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$filename = $path[array_key_last($path)];
echo file_get_contents("/files/upload/documents/".$filename);
```

I assume that You have already working routing

Comment: i already know the file name i just want if any user access `www.example.com/temp/example.pdf`. so he/she can view PDF file without knows the original path of the file where file exits in website.